# action bar not showing extending from a different module

Tags: android, android-actionbar, manifest

I've created a :core module that stores some of my basic activities, some of these should show an actionbar, in the manifest I've something like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".components.home.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".components.activities.ContactsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TranslucentActionBar" >
        </activity>
```

I don't understand why but now that I've created another module :extension that includes :core, the actionbars in that activities seems to not show.

The manifest of extension is very simple:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon" >
    <activity
        android:name=".components.activities.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".components.home.WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Usually this is a problem that concerns themes, but to me everything seems fine, I don't understand why it works when I build simply :core, but it doesn't work when building :extension project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent too much time when the answer was easy.
Pressing Ctrl+click made me see how the theme was made, I've simply switched parent to the old layout.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```